# Circular permutations with opposite gender sitting together

Tags: probability

> How many ways can *n* men and *n* women sit in a round table given that the same gender **never** sit next to each other.

By trial and error, I think that the answer is *n!(n-1)!*

First, I tried *n!n!/2n* because there are *2n* people in the circle but it is wrong, so I tried *(n-1)!(n-1)!*, using 2 circular permutation formulas, which is also wrong. Finally, I end up with *n!(n-1)!* which I think is correct. But why is it only one circular permutation formular and one normal permutation?Why is it not two circular permutation?

Comment: If they all shift over by one seat, is that considered a different arrangement?

Comment: Nope, that it seen as identical.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we label one of the seats as seat 1, and the remainder numbered clockwise to $2n$. Also suppose one of the women is named Alice. We will call two seatings equivalent if they are identical after we rotate the seatings until Alice is sitting in seat 1.

If Alice is in seat 1, all of the women are then seated in the odd numbered seats. And there are (n-1)! such seatings of women (we already know where Alice is sitting!).

Then for each of those seatings of just the women, there are n! distinct ways to seat the men. Thus, your $(n-1)!n!$ total seatings.

You could also think of this as: given a seat labeled 1, the are $2(n!n!)$ possible outcomes - $n!n!$ when seat 1 is occupied by a woman, and $n!n!$ when seat 1 is occupied by a man. We take this "modulo" the $2n$ possible places that an arbitrary woman (Alice) is seated, so the result is $\frac{2(n!n!)}{2n} = (n-1)!n!$.